# Cassandra: data modelling groups

Tags: database-design, cassandra, data-modeling

Im seeking advice how to design the following usecase:

User can be part of an Unit. If he is part of an unit and creates a device it should be visible to all users of the unit. If he is not part of a unit only he should see his own devices.

Im thinking about storing devices in 2 tables: a) device_by_organisation and b) device_by_user. If user is part of an organisation table a) will be used. if he is not part then table b) will be used.

What i dont like about this approach: A device can have sensors. So if devices are splitted into tables then i would have to split sensors as well.

Is there a more elegant approach?

Comment: How about using another field into `device` like `device_type`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with 2 additional tables:

```
device_group {
    group_name text,
    device_id uuid
}
```

and

```
sensour_group {
    group_name text,
    sensor_id uuid
)
```

To get all devices for a group:

```
a) select * from device_group where group_name = 'xyz'
b) select * from device where id in ( 'a)' )
```

Comment: Actually the usage of IN is discouraged. So the way shown above is not the best choice